# Interrupt and resume code from queue in a loop

Tags: c++, assembly, operating-system

I have queue with objects, which are executed sequentially. There is no operating system, I'm just using the hardware and my code:

```
while(true) {
    if( next = queue.next() ) {
        next->do_stuff()
    }
}
```

Now I want to suspend the code which is executed at `next->do_stuff()`, based on some hardware interrupts (there are no more details needed about the hardware interrupts). This suspend should save the state (current instruction) and enqueue the `next` back to the queue, so that the next `do_stuff` of this `next` starts at the last instruction, before suspending it. I know, how to safe the state, but I have no idea, how to return from `do_stuff`. I think, this should be done with assembly.

Some Buzzwords what to search for, would be really nice. Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Generally, if you have an interrupt you can do stuff then resume execution at the same place, no need to requeue stuff. Conversely, if you requeue stuff, you obviously can't resume at the saved instruction, you then want something like `longjmp` that goes back to the while loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jester. I think I can resume at the saved instruction, if a save the stack of the `next`. At first glance, `longjmp` would help me.